# Put a Cytoscape graph inside a Bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cytoscape

I have 4 Bootstrap columns: col-lg-1, col-lg-1, col-lg-4 and col-lg-6 (from left to right).

In the biggest column (col-lg-6), I would like to have a Cytoscape graph. Currently my Cytoscape style is the following (in the `<head>` section):

```
<style type="text/css">
#cy {
      height: 80%;
      width: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 40%;
      top: 20%;
      background:red;
  }
</style>
```

Then in the body section, I have my leftmost column:

```
<div id="cy" class="col-lg-6" style="background-color:grey;">
Some text 

</div>
```

Finally, I have my script also in the body section of the HTML document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    .....
});

});

</script>
```

The problem now is that Cytoscape graph (and the leftmost column) doesn't stack below other columns when the browser resizes (as expected in a Bootstrap behavior).

Can you please show me a somehow detailed solution for this, I do appreciate your expertise very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all include the the **Cytoscape graph section** inside the **col-lg-6**

Get rid of `position: absolute` just set the `height: 100%`

Check the working demo [**here**](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/BLELGW)

Sample structure:

```
<!-- container-fluid : start -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <row>
    <div class="col-sm-6">

       <----Include other stuff here----->

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">

      <!-- graph : start -->
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Graph</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div id="cy-container">
            <div id="cy"></div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- graph : end -->

    </div>


  </row>
</div>
```

Comment: When I remove the div with panel-primary, the cytoscape graph also disappears. Do you know why it is?

Comment: @KhoiBoo I have updated the example without panel. It works fine check the updated demo **[here](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/BLELGW)**.              If my answer helps you kindly upvote, It will help others people too who are looking for the same problem

Answer (score 0):

[my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPfll.jpg)

Thanks for your answer. It works really well.

I adapt it in my code in the following way:

```
<!-- quesType -->  
<div class="col-lg-1" style="background-color:yellow;">
something bla bla bla
</div>

<!-- quesTrans -->
<div class="col-lg-1" style="background-color:pink;"> 
blabla
</div>

<!-- Editor -->
<div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:blue;">
blablabla
</div> 

<div id="cy" class="col-lg-6  " style="background: green; ">

  <!-- graph : start -->
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Graph Khoi</div>
    <div class="panel-body">


    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- graph : end -->

</div>
```

A small problem here: I see nodes on the graph, but when i click on any node, the mouse pointer is not on the node, but somewhere nearby.

Although the "panel-primary" does nothing (in my opinion), if I remove that div then the cytoscape graph also disappear. My cytoscape initialization is a standard one with some nodes and edges. Thank you very much @Joyti Pathania